# How to add a custom view to an activity?

Tags: android

I know this has been asked many times on SO, but somehow I don't get to the solution reading the existing answers.

The most simple thing, I want to add a custom view in an activity.
The custom view `MyView` has a background color, as well as its `subView`.
But the activity is just plain white and does not seem to display the custom view.

Why is that?

MainAcivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        MyView myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);        
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.myapp.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyView.java

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {

        inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this);
        subView = findViewById(R.id.subView);
        //...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    }
}
```

my_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't skip `onLayout` implementation in you snippet then you remove layout logic of your custom view, just don't override it:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved the problem. I had that snipped left over from another implementation. Didn't see the wood for the trees. ‍♂️